# Combine datetime with nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two columns in DB: `StartDate` (datetime column) and `StartTime` (nvarchar column).
`StartDate` contains date when event shoud start. 
`StartTime` contains time when event should start. It is 24hour format (for example, 22:00 or 12:00).

I need to combine `StartDate` with `StarTime` to use it in `WHERE` clause and compare the result with variable. It would look like:

```
WHERE COMBINED_STARTDATE_WITH_STARTIME >= @DATETIME_VARIABLE
```

I am using SQL SERVER 2008.
This is existing DB design and would not like to change it. Probably, I can create third column and combine datetime + startdate into one column, but I am looking for another sollutions (that doesn't touch database).

Comment: If performance is important, you may want to combine the dates and times into another column prior to running any query with the WHERE clause like that.

Comment: Are there any primary keys or identity columns on this table?

Comment: What version of SQL Server please? And why are you storing this separately and using poor data types to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
WHERE 
dateadd(minute, cast(right(starttime, 2) as int),
    dateadd(hour, cast(left(starttime, 2) as int), startdate)) >= @DATETIME_VARIABLE
```

[SQL Fiddle with DateTime Conversion](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0eb43/8)

In the event the start time is `null` then you can use `IsNull()` around the value:

```
WHERE
dateadd(minute, cast(right(isnull(starttime, 0), 2) as int),
    dateadd(hour, cast(left(isnull(starttime, 0), 2) as int), startdate)) >= @DATETIME_VARIABLE
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0eb43/22)

Of course if you are using SQL Server 2008+ you can just cast your value as time:

```
WHERE startdate + IsNull(StartTime, '00:00') >= @DATETIME_VARIABLE
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0eb43/31)

Comment: @rs: `CASE WHEN StartTime IS NOT NULL THEN ... ELSE ... END`